# run a mysql trigger to insert multiple dates

Tags: php, mysql, triggers, date

is there any of running a trigger on my sql to insert dates a row for each date for agiven range.
for example if i send 2011-01-01   to 2011-03-27 the it should insert a unique row to each date. im using php for this. any help will be appreciated .

thanks,
Dakshina

Comment: A trigger, or a stored procedure?

Comment: you basically are not clear about what a trigger is. This is not what a trigger is for, this is better achieved with a stored procedure.

Comment: is that possible with stored procedure.thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hai Dakhsina, you have to write a php code for this....u have to write a seperate function and call it by passing two dates

Comment: ya i have a php code to do this. i was wondering whether this is possible with mysql. thanks for your help.